# The reading of the word

Tags: phonetics

I'm interested in the next information. Is it possible to read the word 'via' ['vaɪə] like a latin variant ['vɪə] in English?

Comment: What research have you done on the question?

Comment: I guess so, when referring to Via Appia.

Comment: The full OED lists BrE **/ˈvʌɪə/** AmE **/vaɪə/, /viə/** as "standard" pronunciations, but because it's still essentially "Latin" rather than "English", other variants might considered at least "credible" to some speakers.

Comment: We British used to have our own peculiar way of pronouncing Latin [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin) , and this has been preserved in some familiar Latin loanwords such as _via, vice versa_ and so on. Otherwise, Latin can be pronounced like Italian (Church Latin) or in a way thought to be closer to Roman pronunciation.

Comment: I was taught to say 'via' like 'we are'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your opinion)